# Caching the profile image in Unity using Facebook SDK

Tags: unity, facebook

Recently for my new game i am implementing the Facebook Login. Currently when i login i show the Profile image to the user.

```
void UpdateUserNameAndImage(bool isLoggedIn) {
    if (isLoggedIn) {
        FB.API ("/me?fields=first_name", HttpMethod.GET, UpdateUserName);
        FB.API ("/me/picture?type=square&height=50&width=50", HttpMethod.GET, UpdateProfileImage);
    } else {

    }
}


private void UpdateProfileImage(IGraphResult result) {
    if(result.Texture != null) {
        facebookLogin_button.GetComponentInChildren<RawImage> ().texture = result.Texture;
    }

}
```

The code is normal. I call it after there is successful login from the user.

**The problem:**
Well the problem is that there should be internet for the profile picture to appear. There must be a call made to the graph api for the image everytime.

I want to show the profile image of the user when there is no internet too.

So i am looking for some kind of cache that Facebook SDK use for the logged in profile that i am not aware of.

Comment: Can you show us your `UpdateProfileImage` callback?

Comment: It looks like you get access to a texture. Is there anything preventing you from saving that texture to disc to load as a fallback next time? (Including any Facebook policies - I know some services have rules against caching personally identifiable data about users, but I don't know Facebook's policy in particular)